# Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes

Tags: mysql, sql

I increased limit by

```
SET @@global.innodb_large_prefix = 1;
```

but my columns are `VARCHAR(2048)` and 3072 bites are not enough for that. It seems that there is no way to increase `innodb_large_prefix` above 3072. Is there any other way around. may be any type of compression or something else? my query is

```
CREATE TABLE UV_Bank_Branches(
  `A Name` VARCHAR( 2048 ) ,
  `B Town` VARCHAR( 2048 ) ,
  `A Range Lower` VARCHAR( 2048 ) ,
  `A Range Upper` VARCHAR( 2048 ) ,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `A Name` , `B Town` , `A Range Lower` , `B Range Upper` )
  )
```

Comment: That's a really, really huge primary key. Do you really need all fields to be jointly unique?

Comment: Its requirement :( so i can't change it. It is used to store records from csv

Comment: Why are these columns so large? Would it perhaps be more appropriate for them to be foreign keys into other tables (normalization)? This would also solve your index problem.

Comment: I want to make them unique because csv file loads very first to sql db but if we compare that table to a modified csv to compare and add new records, then it takes to much time so i want to make them unique this way

Comment: is there a way fast enough to load 8MB csv containing more than 100000 records to different tables and set foreign keys for that as well in few seconds? `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` takes almost 30-35 seocnds